# Cypress could not find spec files

Tags: javascript, docker, cypress, docker-run

I'm trying to run cypress tests inside a docker container.

It works when my test spec files are located inside ./cypress folder as cypress looks for default folder(cypress/integration) but it could not find spec files when i use different test spec files path( trying to override default folder);

I'm using below docker command ;

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:6.2.1 cypress run --config integrationFolder=tests --spec 'tests/spec.js'
```

ERROR:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

tests/spec.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own test folder path by configuring cypress.json file as below;

```
{   
    "integrationFolder": "tests"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can try to write your exact workaround in a cypress.json

{
"integrationFolder": "cypress/integration"
}

I think it's mostly working. I am also writing for this particular error..

Comment: Good answer, a few suggestions though. Try formatting the code properly and providing more explanation on what the answer solves.